# Can I add priming sugar second time after beer turned out flat?

Tags: beer, bottling, carbonation

Bottled a batch of ale three weeks ago using bulk priming method. When there’s almost nothing left in a pale I’ve noticed that most of sugar didn’t dissolve staying at the bottom, which never happened before. I waited for three weeks, opened a bottle and, as I was expecting, it turned out absolutely flat.

So my question is would it make sense to re-bottle this batch again while adding more priming sugar or is it simply cannot be saved? Any help or advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can, sugar won't dissolve easily at low temp.  Make a sugar solution first. To maximize the ratio of sugar to water - boil water then add 330 g sugar per 100 ml water. Cool down the solution and add 2 ml per bottle to get a 7 gram liquid sugar addition for priming. (7 grams was recomended below and will be about 3.3 volumes of CO2 at 70 degree storage temp). You can add up to 500 g per 100 ml but I used 330 as an example.

Comment: Thanks for detailed instructions, I really appreciate it. I’ll do exactly that!

Comment: No problem! Note: it's 10 ml not 1 ml for 33 g. Just noticed and corrected that.

Comment: You are adding (33g/660mL=) 50g/L of sugar in your beer for bottle priming ?? This is gonna blow up the bottles, usually you add around 7g/L.

Comment: The process is good, but that is a very large amount of sugar per bottle it seems.

Comment: Seems quite dangerous to me, indeed.

Comment: @JeanMi: My mistake, I've made corrections based on your comment. I generally use a calculator such as: https://www.northernbrewer.com/pages/priming-sugar-calculator

Comment: Allright! Actually this calculator effectively gives similar results to my advice, the range of CO2 vol you want to achieve are typically between 2.5 and 3.5vol